# MVC 4 Email.Send Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, postal

I am using Postal to send a confirmation email to a new registered user. But it gets caught in when it hits email.send();. Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                string confirmationToken =  
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                                new { model.Email}, true);

                dynamic email = new Email("RegEmail");
                email.To = model.Email;
                email.UserName = model.UserName;
                email.ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken;
                email.HostLocation = Request.Url.Host + ':' + Request.Url.Port;

                email.Send();

                return RedirectToAction("RegisterStepTwo", "Account");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Festival");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: What is the error message and is SMTP configured in Web.config?

Comment: RegEmail does exist and the error is:

Comment: If you get an exception at `email.Send()` how are you catching it? You could use `catch(Exception ex){ }` as well.

Comment: Sorry @mikhairu, here is the error _The method or operation is not implemented._

Comment: Yes I have an exception there to see if there is a problem on registering a user, if there was a problem before it gets into the the try block, it would fall into the catch block.